# Why do I get EJBTransactionRolledbackException instead of OptimisticLockException?

Tags: jpa, jboss

I work with Wildfly and OpenJPA. I have a situation of Optimistic Lock Exception.

The error message that I get is:

> 00:08:29,373 **WARN**  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (default task-39)
>   ARJUNA012125: TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion - failed for
>   SynchronizationImple< 0:ffffc0a82f91:-3d767137:5a736fa1:d7c,
>   org.jboss.as.txn.service.internal.tsr.JCAOrderedLastSynchronizationList@244256b9
>
> > :  org.apache.openjpa.persistence.**OptimisticLockException**: Optimistic
> >     locking errors were detected when flushing to the data store.  The
> >     following objects may have been concurrently modified in another
> >     transaction: [com.earnix.eo.entities.optimizer.PricingMixEntity-30400]
> >     ....
>
> 00:08:29,381 **ERROR** [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-39)
>   WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component PricingRuleAccessor
>   for method public abstract java.util.List
>   com.earnix.eo.sessions.navigator.PricingRuleAccessor.releasePricingMix(int,int)
>   throws
>   com.earnix.utils.EOException,com.earnix.eo.sessions.utils.EODeadlockException,java.rmi.RemoteException:
>   javax.ejb.**EJBTransactionRolledbackException**: Transaction rolled back
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleEndTransactionException(CMTTxInterceptor.java:137)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:117)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:279)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.processInvocation(EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.java:79)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbSuspendInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbSuspendInterceptor.java:53)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.EjbExceptionTransformingInterceptorFactories$1.processInvocation(EjbExceptionTransformingInterceptorFactories.java:75)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
>       at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:328)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.access$100(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:67)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler$1.run(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:201)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.processMessage(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:263)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.VersionOneProtocolChannelReceiver.processMessage(VersionOneProtocolChannelReceiver.java:213)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versiontwo.VersionTwoProtocolChannelReceiver.processMessage(VersionTwoProtocolChannelReceiver.java:76)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.VersionOneProtocolChannelReceiver.handleMessage(VersionOneProtocolChannelReceiver.java:159)
>       at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionChannel$5.run(RemoteConnectionChannel.java:456)
>       at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl$TrackingExecutor$1.run(EndpointImpl.java:731)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
>       at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1212)
>       at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:126)
>       at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:89)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:91)
>       ... 47 more
>   Caused by:  org.apache.openjpa.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Optimistic locking errors were detected when flushing to the data store.  The following objects may have been concurrently modified in another transaction: [com.earnix.eo.entities.optimizer.PricingMixEntity-30400]
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.newFlushException(BrokerImpl.java:2357)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:2205)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flushSafe(BrokerImpl.java:2103)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.beforeCompletion(BrokerImpl.java:2021)
>       at org.jboss.as.txn.service.internal.tsr.JCAOrderedLastSynchronizationList.beforeCompletion(JCAOrderedLastSynchronizationList.java:116)
>       at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:76)
>       at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:368)
>       at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:91)
>       at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:162)
>       at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1200)
>       ... 50 more
>   Caused by:  org.apache.openjpa.persistence.OptimisticLockException: An optimistic lock violation was detected when flushing object instance "com.earnix.eo.entities.optimizer.PricingMixEntity-30400" to the data store.  This indicates that the object was concurrently modified in another transaction.
>   FailedObject: com.earnix.eo.entities.optimizer.PricingMixEntity-30400
>       at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.flushAndUpdate(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:124)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.BatchingPreparedStatementManagerImpl.batchOrExecuteRow(BatchingPreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:100)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.BatchingPreparedStatementManagerImpl.flushAndUpdate(BatchingPreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:83)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.flushInternal(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:100)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.flush(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:88)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.ConstraintUpdateManager.flush(ConstraintUpdateManager.java:550)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.ConstraintUpdateManager.flush(ConstraintUpdateManager.java:107)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.BatchingConstraintUpdateManager.flush(BatchingConstraintUpdateManager.java:59)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractUpdateManager.flush(AbstractUpdateManager.java:104)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractUpdateManager.flush(AbstractUpdateManager.java:77)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.flush(JDBCStoreManager.java:731)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingStoreManager.flush(DelegatingStoreManager.java:131)

My problem is that EJBTransactionRolledbackException is thrown and not OptimisticLockException. Therefore, my code doesn't consider the exception as OptimisticLockException. Do you know how I can make Wildfly/JPA throw an EJBTransactionRolledbackException ?

I also looked at the 'cause' field of TransactionRolledbackException and I see there null. 
[image]

Some code:

```
@Override
    public List<PricingMixHeader> releasePricingRule(PricingMixHeader header) throws EOException {
        for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
            try {
                return pricingRuleAccessor.releasePricingMix(header.getPk(), getSessionPk());
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                DeadlockUtils.handleRemoteException(e, i);
            } catch (EODeadlockException e) {
                // recover from the deadlock
                DeadlockUtils.recover(i, e.getOriginalExceptionStack());
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code in the client side. pricingRuleAccessor.releasePricingMix(...) is a remote-mothod invocation call to a method in server side. In the server side Optimistic Lock Exception occured and then RemoteException was caught (TransactionRolledbackException inherits from RemoteException).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest 2 things:

1) You could call a `em.flush()` before the point that the '**OptimisticLockException**' exception occurs, to get this exception and then throw it as you want.

2) Other possibility is to ignore the details that are ocurring an **OptimisticLockException**, and create a new '**MyRemoteException**' ( an ApplicationException that extends EJBException). It'd be like that:

```
@ApplicationException(rollback = true)
public class MyRemoteException extends EJBException {
  ...
}
```

Throw this exception to be caught by your 'view layer' and then it will decide what information to show.

Answer (score 0):

JBoss always wraps the thrown exception, in your case OptimisticLockException, in a EJBTransactionRollbackException when the thrown exception is a RuntimeException that causes a rollback.

In your client code you must check for EJBTransactionRollbackException and then check if the cause is a OptimisticLockException:

```
try {
...
} catch (EJBTransactionRollbackException e) {
    if (e.getCause() instanceof OptimisticLockException) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the cause field is null. I edited the post.

Comment: Why do you use OpenJPA and not Hibernate?

Comment: No seriously that doesn't make sense. Is your JBoss JPA module changed to OpenJPA or do you deploy OpenJPA with the application?

Comment: And in your debug console I see TransactionRolledbackException no EJBTransactionRollbackException. Can you show some code?

Comment: How do you do remoting? EJB remoting?

Comment: Can you post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: please see explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10942613/12980819 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/19563956/12980819